# Connect to local SQL database on computer usin pymysql

Tags: python, sql

I tried to access my database on my local computer using pymysql using

```
db=pymysql.connect(host="localhost", db="all_data")
```

but I get "cannot connect to MySQL server Win Error 10061"

Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the username and password for your running Mysql Hosts.

```
db = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='your username', passwd='your mysql password', db='all_data', port=your port)
```

You don't need to specify the port if MySQL is running on port 3306 which is the default port for MySQL.